# What to dynamically format a column of Gridview to hyperlink of a dynamically SQL bounded to Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, hyperlink

I have a sql query (**final_query**) which dynamically gets generated and bound to existing GridView,

```
String final_query = "select CandidateID, CandidateName, CandidateResume from Candidate_Dump";
//database connection
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strconnection);
DataSet set1;= new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter adp;= new SqlDataAdapter(final_query, con);
adp.Fill(set1);
GridView1.DataSource = set1.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

the columns in the final_query vary as per the choice of fields in which user is interested based on previous form, but if the user selects CandidateResume  as choice the field is expected to be shown as a Hyperlink column, So when the user clicks on this link; it gets redirected to other page where candidate's resume is displayed.

So how can we conditionally format the Resume column to Hyperlink only when it is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a HyperLinkColumn,  or a [TemplateField](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs) if your expression is too complicated for the HyperLinkField, in your `GridView` definition to format your hyperlink appropriately.

Comment: Thanks @Cam Bruce But I am fairly newly to GridView, if you can give some reference link or paste some example code it will help a lot!

Comment: In your ASPX page designer, you can change the columns of your data source. Make sure all your columns are there, including your hyperlink column.

Comment: Here is a tutorial to get your started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479339.aspx

Comment: Thanks again @Cam Bruce I agree using the design mode I can bound it to the required columns. But the only trick part in my case is,until run time I am unaware of the number of columns which will be displayed    in the gridview. I need to create DataBound/TemplateField on fly and attach to my GridView throug my #C code and not fix through Design mode. Please guide me with this context. Thanks!

Comment: @ks_baba I would post a separate question for that. Cam Bruce has already answered the original question you asked. What you're now asking for is large enough in scope to warrant a new question (make sure you look for existing questions first that might answer it).

Comment: Thanks @msm8bball Frankly I am not sure how to frame it in correct way  with respect to dynamic GridView. You may help me in the same.